# Сгенерировать необходимое количество элементов html через js

Tags: javascript, html

На сайте есть переменная $OTHER$, в которой мной задаются числа от 1 до 30.

Допустим $OTHER$ = '5'

Мне необходимо сгенерировать следующий html:

```
<a href="seriya-1"><span>1</span></a>
<a href="seriya-2"><span>2</span></a>
<a href="seriya-3"><span>3</span></a>
<a href="seriya-4"><span>4</span></a>
<a href="seriya-5"><span>5</span></a>
```

Как все это сгенерировать через js?

Comment: И с чем у вас проблема?

Comment: с тем, что таких элементов может быть до 300 на странице. для каждой страницы определенное кол-во. прописывать все это вручную? сложновато..

Comment: @ser1ko через цикл можно выводить элементы

Comment: @DmitryB. B. пожалуйста, расскажите как? я чайник полный

Comment: _до 300 на странице_ 
как определяется это к-во?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предыдущий код генерирует HTML вставку и так же в цикле производит её вставку в DOM. Этот подход заставляет браузер раз за разом отрисовывать страницу, что негативно сказывается на производительности.

**Наиболее правильным будет следующее решение:**

```js
"use strict";

let fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(); // HTML fragment
let amount = 5; // items amount

for (let i = 1; i <= amount; i++) {
    let url = document.createElement('a');
    let span = document.createElement('span');

    span.innerHTML = i;
    url.href = 'seriya-' + i;
    url.appendChild(span);
    
    fragment.appendChild(url);
}

document.body.appendChild(fragment);
```

Answer (score 0):

Через циклы. Советую подучить JavaScript

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
document.body.innerHTML += "<a class='movies' href='seriya-"+i+"'><span>"+i+"</span></a>";
}
```

```css
.movies:before {
  content:"Серия ";

}
.movies {
  display:block;
  padding:10px;
  border-radius:3px;
  background:#eee;
  color:#333;
  border:none;
  margin:3px;
  font-family:sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант на jQuery:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var $block = $('#block');
  var num = 5;

  for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    $block.append('<a href="seriya-' + i + '"><span>' + i + '</span></a>');
  }
  
});
```

```css
#block {
  width: 200px;
  background: lightgreen;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#block a {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="block"></div>
```

Comment: _jquery , append_ . Ниже ответ лучше, тем что страница будет работать на много быстрее.